# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:..No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a rest call to a webservice using this code:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: "serviceUrl",
    type: "POST",
    data: { method : 'classic',                                 
    text : 'test'}, 
    success: function( result ) {
    alert("OK");
    }
});
```

I got this error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load "http:...". No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'my url' is therefore not allowed access.

I read it is a cross domain ajax request problem. Is there a way to avoid this, or another way to make this call in javascript?

Comment: proxify request server side

Comment: Does the service require an api-key?

Comment: no, the service requires username & password but I put it into the data field (it's not shown in my code)

Comment: Is the username/password related to the current user using the application, or is it application-wide. Would it be hazardous for your users to be able to see said username/password? if you use client-side javascript to make this request, anyone who uses this application will be able to see the username/password.